# Making WCF web service look like a ASMX web service when asked?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, xcelsius

I'm currently using Xcelsius to connect to my WCF web service, however it doesn't work. Googling around I see that Xcelsius can't connect to WCF web services but can't seem to find out why.

Assuming the web service gives away what type it is (WCF or ASMX) is it possible to perhaps spoof this? Something similar changing your user agent in a browser.

#### Edit

Xcelsius is expecting the address to the services WSDL (http://localhost:3951/Service1.svc?wsdl). As for the format that my WCF service is emiting, it's

```
public string GetData(int value)
{
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

I've also tried using FlatWSDL, however that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: you're going to need to provide more details.  Exactly what format is Xcelsius expecting?  And what format is the WCF service emitting?

Comment: You can try [AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx)

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan: Unfortunately, none of the `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode` options work. :(

Comment: Looking at the Url you provided makes me think that you are using `localhost` while the XCelsius (whatever it is) could be installed on another machine.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: The address is correct because I'm able to access it via my browser.

Comment: The question is not whether YOU can access it but whether the XCelsius can access it. Are you sure about that?

Comment: I think it's more a case that Xcelsius *can* access it however it does not accept WCF services for one reason or another. So if I can make my ASMX service appear like a WCF. I'm only really wanting to do this so I can use DI.

Comment: please publish here a sample soap that the service excepts

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `basicHttpBinding` in your service, and will look like an ASMX service to any consumer.

That still might not be enough, if the consumer is expecting a particular format. You would then need to duplicate the expected format.